# I dont know how to blend my csv code. Ill show you what I mean below

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am making a web scraper and storing it in a CSV file on Excel. The only problem is that it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WJlk.gif. If you can see, my rows are separated where they should be together. Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
page_url = 'https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html'

uClient = uReq(page_url)
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

containers  = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"callout"})
out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"
headers = "Deaths \n"

f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)
Deaths = containers[0].span.text
print("Deaths: " + Deaths + "\n")

f.write(Deaths + "\n")
f.close()
```

I don't know how to make this any better and I looked it up on youtube many times. Any advice would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the data, you are getting contains commas and you are storing it in a CSV which splits the text at commas so you should either use a TSV which separates the data at tabs or remove commas from your data I have provided both the solutions below and you should also use context managers and for more info on context manager check out this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/). Hope this was helpful.

1. TSV Method

   ```
   out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.tsv"
   headers = "Deaths \n"

   Deaths = containers[0].span.text
   print("Deaths: " + Deaths + "\n")

   with open(out_filename, "w") as f:
       f.write(headers)
       f.write(Deaths + "\n")
   ```
2. Removing Commas Method

   ```
   out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"
   headers = "Deaths \n"

   Deaths = containers[0].span.text.replace(",", "")
   print("Deaths: " + Deaths + "\n")

   with open(out_filename, "w") as f:
       f.write(headers)
       f.write(Deaths + "\n")
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much but how do I implement this in my HTML code. I am going to need the commas for that and I can't remove the commas

Comment: Then you can just use the TSV method I mentioned above and you don't have to remove the commas then.

Comment: How do I do the tsv. I didnt see that as a save option on Excel.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do if you can tell me?

Comment: I am trying to make a website that displays basic covid info. ik its nothing new its just for my personal bennifet. I want to save the webscraper in a csv file so that I can call for it in my html code. Thats all I want to do.

Comment: Then you can just save the file as a .tsv as shown and when you will call it from the HTML code just change the extension from .csv to .tsv then you don't have to remove any commas and the project will work without any problems and if you have any problems with the HTML code as well just ask. Just change this  ```out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.csv"``` to this ```out_filename = "usacovid_deaths.tsv"```

Comment: Thank you so much but can I save as a tsv in excel?

Comment: Yes, you can open it and save it in excel. It is just a different file type. And flag your answer as answered so it is easy for people to find it.

Comment: thank you so muc, How do I call for it in html though? Sorry im such a beginner at coding lol.

Comment: Also, it saved as a text doc. Is that normal

Comment: No problem everyone is at a  point of time. So to open such file you need to learn javascript and jquery but If you don't want to just use flask API in python to do it. Here is a great [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqhxxeeTbu0&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-n4vJJybUVV3Un_NFS5EOgX) to learn flask.

Comment: So how do I call for it?

Comment: You cant directly open files in HTML there has to be a backend like jquery or flask it's your choice which one to learn. I would recommend flask as you already know python.

Comment: No, your HTML code needs a backend so it can arse the information from the file and display it.

Comment: Can you explain that to me like im really dumb bc I dont know what that means.

Comment: So it means that the what is displayed on the screen is the frontend i.e your HTML code and if you want to just hardcode the values in it you can but as you are planning to display the number of deaths from COVID-19 so you need a backend i.e Python that will download the data and pass it to the HTML code to display it as the data is always changing and to pass the data between Python and HTML as they both are different languages we need a framework which is flask,

Comment: How do i do this though?

Comment: can I email you?